# angular typeahead event for focused item

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I am trying to show some information based on the currently focused item on the typeahead dropdown list. I looked through the documentation of angular typeahead but i could not find anything related to what is currently in focus.

http://plnkr.co/edit/w6F0INtBospWwp7e9VrX?p=preview shows the on select event working but i am looking for the focused item even before the selection.

```
<h4>Static arrays</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{selected | json}} | Focus : </pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected"  uib-typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">
```